# Live Edit does not work in my WebStorm 5.0

Tags: webstorm

Live Edit does not work in my WebStorm 5.0, and I have installed jb.crx for webstorm.

I have try these steps.

1. menu "view" -> select "Live Edit"
2. menu "view" -> select "Open In Browser"

when I changing my html file, but nothing happens in chrome browser.

Could you help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/LiveEdit.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the path to the browser is correct (seems ironic but my chrome is installed in \program files so it was a problem)

Make sure, that the extension is installed in chrome - webstorm has a wiki for this. One special thing to remember is to allow the extension access to local files

Finally, it only worked for me after restarting both browser and webstorm

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the JetBrains IDE Chrome extension from the Chrome Store :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/reviews

Answer (score 0):

You should also configure Debug Configuration like described in http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/live-edit-in-phpstorm/